# How to handle extremely small numbers in java

Tags: java

I am developing a java application for sentiment analysis using Naive Bayes classifier. But while computing the probability the results are very small numbers due to which we are getting an output which is zero. Using BigDecimal didn't help.

Comment: Could you show examples of your computations? BigDecimal is the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure that your actual question has anything to do with "small numbers in java", and not just a buggy Naive Bayes implementation?

Comment: How small is 'extremely small'? A `double` can go pretty small.

Comment: would something like x = 1 % 0.0000000000001 overflow x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply using `BigDecimal` numbers and wrap them into a custom class :

```
public class InfinitesimalNumber {
    private BigDecimal mantisse;
    private int exponent;
}
```

However, you would have to implement all the maths, which would not be so easy even if `BigDecimal` would do most of the job.

Comment: `BigDecimal` already has a built-in 32-bit integer for `scale`, and it uses base `10`. But `10^{-2000000000}` is already such a ridiculously tiny number, that it certainly would not help to add another 32 bits for the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, BigDecimal should have been useful.

Another suggestion can be to use logarithm for multiplication.For example to compute product of a*b*c*...*z you can use

```
product = exp(log(a) + log(b) + log(c) + ... + log(z))
```

Also if the result is really extremely small then does that probability needs to be taken into consideration? I am not sure but just asking out of curiosity.